# Heroku-20 установка Rails приложения. Неверная версия Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Проблема с установкой приложения Rails на heroku.
У меня в Gemfile указана версия 2.7.4.
В Gemfile.lock так же указано, версия 2.7.4.
rvm использует версию 2.7.4 тоже - rvm use 2.7.4.

Heroku использует 20 stack.
В документации сказано, что 20 stack поддерживает версию 2.7.4.

При попытке запушить вылетает ошибку

```
Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.4
Bundler Output: Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.4
```

Я выполнил команду для проверки версии и убедился, что в хероку стоит версия 2.7.0.

```
heroku run ruby -v
```

Я пробовал билд хероку с нужной версией.

```
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

Там используется версия 2.7.4 как раз. Мне не помогло. Ошибка в документации получается и поддерживается только версия 2.7.0?
Есть ли способ обновить версию на хероку?

Comment: Может в файле `.ruby-version` указана неверная?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была при пуше приложения в хероку.
Была указана версия ruby-2.7.0 в /bin/bundle.

Можно убрать версию, оставить просто ruby